# Vuetify Autocomplete dropdown not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify autocomplete component in my nuxt project. its not working as expected. problem is when i start typing it fetches data using api but it doesn't show me results in dropdown, but once i click outside input box and then again focus on search box, then it shows the dropdown. but i want to see the results on every key press.

here is the code so far.

```html
<v-autocomplete v-model="pickupairport" name="pickupairport" :items="airports" :loading="isLoading" :search-input.sync="aptsearch" chips clearable hide-details hide-selected label="Search for a airport..." solo>
  <template v-slot:no-data>
      <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-title>
              Search for your favorite
              <strong>Destinations</strong>
          </v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ attr, on, item, selected }">
      <v-chip v-bind="attr" :input-value="selected" color="blue-grey" class="white--text" v-on="on">
          <v-icon left>
              mdi-bitcoin
          </v-icon>
          <span v-text="item.name"></span>
      </v-chip>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
      <v-list-item-avatar color="indigo" class="text-h5 font-weight-light white--text">
          {{ item.name.charAt(0) }}
      </v-list-item-avatar>
      <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
          <v-list-item-subtitle>{{item.cityName}}, {{item.countryName}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
      </v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-action>
          <v-icon>fa-airports</v-icon>
      </v-list-item-action>
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

this is script part

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      aptsearch: null,
      items: [],
      model: null,
      tab: null,
      pickupairport: '',
      airports: [],
      isLoading: false,
      uuid: this.$uuid.v4(),
    }
  },
  watch: {
    model(val) {
      if (val != null) this.tab = 0
      else this.tab = null
    },
    aptsearch(val) {
      // Items have already been loaded
      if (this.items.length > 0) return

      this.isLoading = true

      // Lazily load input items
      fetch(`${process.env.EXPRESS_API_URL}/airports/find`, {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            aptsearchkey: this.aptsearch
          })
        })
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          this.airports = []
          data.forEach((item) => this.airports.push(item))
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
        .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false))
    },
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the Vue devtools just after the axios call?

Comment: i don't know why but by adding no-filter in autocomplete, started working.

Comment: What does this prop do?